# Detect WP7 phone like Zune software

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

When I connhect my Windows Phone 7 device to my desktop, Zune automatically starts.
I need to develop an application that have the same behavior.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a Windows Phone 8 device?

Comment: Lol... my mistake. Sorry. It is a Windows Phone 7 device.

Comment: Poll the USB devices...Watch for the specfic device being annouced by the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post [Start program on usb hardware plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412910/start-program-on-usb-hardware-plugin)

So, you need to create a windows service which will polling connected usb-devices and starts your application.

Comment: also you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices