# Get type of device inserted to windows 8 pc via USB port

Tags: windows-8, usb

I've been asked to work on a project for Windows 8 where I have to detect:

1. Type of device inserted to USB port (mass storage drive or android phone or windows phone etc.)
2. Port in which device was inserted. (if I have 4 USB ports in PC then identify which port received new device)
3. Detect when the device was ejected from the PC

Are there some managed C# API's that can be used to query or if there are some callbacks that can be subscribes to.

Any help or direction will be very useful. 
Thanks

Comment: You might check this other thread on Stack Overflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412910/start-program-on-usb-hardware-plugin

Answer (score -1):

You don't specify whether you are writing a desktop app, or a Modern UI app.  If it is the latter, I'm afraid you are going to be out of luck as this level of information is simply not passed down to the app's sandbox.

You may have better luck with a desktop app.  I don't have any direct experience of doing what you ask for, but I do remember having read that it may be possible through .NET.

Comment: Its a desktop app that I have to implement.